# Binding entities with foreign key to datalist

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have the following code:

```
var devices = from d in ctx.Devices.Include("DeviceGroups")
    where d.DeviceEnabled == true
    select d;
dlTerminals.DataSource = devices;
```

On the front end I do the following:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlTerminals" runat="server" DataKeyField="DeviceId" GridLines="None" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="100%">
    <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("DeviceGroups.GroupName")%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

But I get the following error:

> does not contain a property with the name 'GroupName'.

Comment: i am not sure.I think this is the problem of EF :( not because of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
select new { d.DeviceId, d.MAC, d.DeviceType, d.LastConnectTime, d.DeviceGroups.FirstOrDefault().GroupName };
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are developing asp.net flattening the data is probably the best solution. You may also consider adding a property to your class like

```
public string DeviceGroupName
{
    get
    {
        return this.DeviceGroups.FirstOrDefault();
    }

}
```